# Is this a valid DFA for (a|b)*abb?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I'm trying to come up with an alternate DFA for accepting `(a|b)*abb` than the one present in the dragon book. Here's the one I tried:

[image: Alternative DFA accepting strings that match regex (a|b)*abb]

It seems valid to me but I'm not sure. Also, is there a way to check for validity of automatons so that I don't end up bugging you guys next time?

Comment: Given two DFAs, you can check whether they accept the same language via the product automaton. There might even be libraries implementing this algorithm.

Comment: Your DFA does not accept $a b b$, which is part of your language (shortest accepted strings are $a a b b$ and $b a b b$),

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, or build minimal automata for each, and compare. Look at e.g. [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org) or [Automata Tutor](http://www.automatatutor.com) for some easy to use tools to fool around with automata (not just finite ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DFA does not recognize $(a|b)^*abb$. For example it does not recognize $abb$.

Comment: Yep! It doesn't. Thanks :^)